# What is the exact correspondence between light and an alternating electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, electric-fields

When discussing the high-frequency dielectric constant $\epsilon_{\infty}$, it will be said that it is used to describe the response of the dielectric to the applied high-frequency alternating electric field $\mathbf{E}_{app}$, but some say it is the effect of the dielectric on light. Although I know that light is also an electromagnetic wave, I don't understand how light acts as an electric field, and what is the quantitative correspondence between light parameters such as frequency $\nu$, wavelength $\lambda$, etc. and the electric field $\mathbf{E}$?